# EventDrops for D3.js (from marmelab) - how to tweak example code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, d3.js, event-drops

I stumbled upon the non-nodejs version of the [EventDrops](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops) library for D3, and I was able to reproduce the example on my own server. See this blog post [here](http://www.devixgroup.com/blog/2015/01/using-ajax-polling-with-d3-js-eventdrops-project/) for more information and the example code.

However, could somebody please dodge me in the right direction or provide me with code for the following two problems I'm currently facing:

1. Instead of the real-time monitoring, I would like to load a CSV file with dates to display. How can I achieve this?
2. And second, how can I display more information while hoovering over an entry from the graph? The demo from the link above shows only limited information, but I would like to load up multiple rows from the CSV and show them while hoovering. Like in the [example](https://marmelab.com/EventDrops/) from the original EventDrops library team, but without using nodejs.

Thank you all so much for your time and your answers.

Clarification to point 1: The CSV file will have the following structure:

```
name,date,comment
google,"2017-03-06 17:00","some comment about the event"
facebook,2017-02-15 11:13,"again a comment"
google,"2017-01-01 12:13","older google event"
```

[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16363/mark) was so kind to put some code together (see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BqAyEM9Yo6YeG9bHSLc3?p=preview)). However, I was not able to run this code with my CSV from above. Could somebody please help me? Thanks!

Best regards,
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

For your first point, you can turn a CSV file into JavaScript plain object quite easily using [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/). You would then be able to import your file using something like:

```
const data = Papa.parse(csv);
```

For your second question, you have access to the whole data row in each events. For instance, referring to the [EventDrops demo](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops/blob/master/demo/demo.js), you can access your data directly via, for instance:

```
const chart = d3.chart.eventDrops()
    .mouseover((row, index) => {
        // if you need to access several rows, use data[index+1] for instance
    })
```

For hovering yet, it is not really trivial, and you should handle `mouseover` and `mouseout` events manually, as shown in previous demo link.